# In WinEdt 7: How to typeset Arabic, Persian and Urdu properly?

Tags: unicode, winedt, arabic

WinEdt 7 has been released with a claimed support of UTF8. It is true that now the arabic letters are showing correctly, but the default setting are still far from being useful.

first, the arabic, persian and urdu words are made of connected letters (cursive writing), and winedt is showing them separated like latin words!

second, the arabic, persian and urdu languages are right-to-left languages, and I didn't see a way to switch to right to left (RTL) mode in WinEdt 7 !!

Can somebody suggest a solution for these problems (if any)?

Comment: I suggest that you ask your questions on the winedt mailing list.

Comment: official answer from the winedt mailing list http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/WinEdt/message/11875

Answer (score 0):

In the head (preamble) add this packege (2 lines):

```
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1]{Rasheeq}
```

Then write the arabic text between:

```
\begin{arab}
% Arabic text here
\end{arab}
```

or

```
\textarab{Arabic text here}
```

Comment: The question is about editor environment not tex output

Answer (score 0):

If the program is showing them separated, it's hard to believe that it supports utf8, or if that specific font you're using for display is not working.

Even if it does not, arabxetex allows for input in latin characters, which should work for those languages. Just download the Scheherazade font, put

```
\usepackage{arabxetex}
```

in the preamble, and do some tests.

Of course you must run xelatex.

If it does not work, just download another editor or use your system's default.

Comment: The question is about editor environment not tex output